# htaccess regex wordpress not working

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site set up with some custom redirect rules set up. The weird thing is I am sure these all of these were working before but now some of them no longer function.

Here is the complete htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^properties/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z\+\'.]+) /properties/?prov=$1&city=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^properties/([0-9]+) /properties/?id=$1 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$ /properties/?id=$1 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^expand.php?id=([0-9]+) /properties/?id=$1 [R,NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

right now the only rule that actually works (other than the directory change for wordpress itself) is

```
 RewriteRule ^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$ /properties/?id=$1 [R,NC]
```

I've tried throwing in simple rules to test, like

```
 RewriteRule ^/bob /contact [R,NC]
```

but that doesn't work either

*** Edit**  the below issue was fixed and is definitely not related to the issue above (but I'll leave it here in case there was a comment that referenced it)*

Also, not sure if this gives any insight but on the page where the redirect actually works, my wordpress theme is broken, the wp_footer never fires and the rest of the page fails

Comment: @zx81: No no I won't answer since your answer is good enough. I didn't comment to make you delete your answer Please undelete it as your answer is good.

Comment: I missed whatever was deleted here, can somebody fill me in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteRule ^bob/?$ /about [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^properties/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z+'.]+)/?$ /properties/?prov=$1&city=$2 [R,NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(?:properties/)?([0-9]+)/?$ /properties/?id=$1 [R,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible causes... You aren't enabling `mod_rewrite` until after your `RewriteRules`, the custom rules should be included inside their own `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag with `RewriteEngine on` preceding them, and you probably want to set `RewriteBase` to whatever the root of your site is (perhaps `/wordpress` subdirectory? you may want to include what you would like these rules to rewrite to and from.) You cannot match on a querystring within a `RewriteRule` either, you have to use a `RewriteCond`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^properties/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z\+\'.]+) /properties/?prov=$1&city=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^properties/([0-9]+) /properties/?id=$1 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{5,5})$ /properties/?id=$1 [R,NC]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also updated `^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$` to the form `^([0-9]{5,5})$` which is a bit more readable.

Your example/test should look like the following - omit the `/` because it is set in the `RewriteBase`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^bob /about [R,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: no dice..  I wrapped my rules in the <IfMOdule> tags and tried both RewriteBase/ and RewriteBase /wordpress and had the same results as before.  the one rule that did work before still works though

Comment: What are you trying to rewrite to/from?

Comment: And do your WordPress permalinks work or do they just use the post ID?

Comment: and I added in a new dummy rule just to test and it's not working either:  RewriteRule ^/bob /about [L]

Comment: What is the URL you are trying and what do you want it to be rewritten to though? Is it under a `wordpress` subdirectory? Etc, etc.

Comment: my dummy example should be  http://www.sample.com/bob redirecting to http://www.sample.com/about

Comment: sorry, first post on stackoverflow. keep hitting enter expecting a line break!   I have wordpress installed in the subdirectory but it's set up to appear as if it's installed in the root (that's the second part of my htaccess file)

Comment: The bob/about example is incorrect if the `RewriteBase /` is set - you should use `RewriteRule ^bob /about [R,NC]`

Comment: FYI the `expand.php?id=..` won't work because rewrite rule pattern doesn't match query strings. Also try `[L]` flag to each rewrite rule otherwise it will fall to Wordpress rules.

Comment: so I managed to hack it to a functional state. Instead of sending it to `/properties/?id=$1` i had to add in the whole domain `http://sample.com/properties/?id=$1` .. making this change for all of the rules has "fixed" the problem

Comment: Hmm, OK. That's not how it's supposed to work, so i would be careful. Check out RewriteCond if you want to match on the query string.